# Screen resolution higher than monitor specs

Tags: graphics, resolution

Is there any magical or non-magical way to increase screen resolution for my monitor that officially does 1366 x 768? With my graphics card, I could do 1920, and when I actually do that, the image is very "unclean" on the screen...

I run Ubuntu 10.10, on an HP Pavilion with a GeForce 315. My monitor is a HD ready Samsung LE32C450... my smaller previous monitor had no problem showing a 1920 resolution, and my obvious mishap was to assume a much bigger screen would support at least this same resolution...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already said you can change the resolution to one higher than your monitor supports (I'm guessing it's a feature of the display). Another way to do it would be the [newrez script](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/newrez+-+Screen+resolution+with+scaling?content=134686) by Marc Brumlik.

But I'm afraid that won't change anything. 
There just aren't enough pixels to display text cleanly.

You can always decrease the size of the text if your display feels a bit cramped. To do that, go to *System → Preferences → Appearance → Fonts → Details...* and set your display resulution to a lower value:

[image]

Thanks to the good design of the Ubuntu font, even 50 dpi is very readable, provided your display operates at its native resolution.

For the best results with most fonts, the resolution should be divisible by 12.

Comment: I am glad that some assumptions about "computer-stuff" start being correct ;). It didn't make sense and that's why I mentioned magical means, but I thought there must be something I don't know that might do it. I will have a look at this tonight, but I am already considering a new screen.. ;)